# How to perform cross-site ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Browsers don't allow cross-site AJAX calls (it's a security restriction). 
Is there any possible solution ?

### EDIT

I control only the caller website

Comment: Do you control both websites?

Comment: which site do you control? The caller or the callee? If you control the callee you can probably implement a JSONP solution.

Comment: Ok, so is JSONP an option from the callee's website? If so, then you can just provide a callback method for the callee in the query string of your request.

Comment: Check out CORS. If the callee web-site sends out a `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com` header, you'll be able to read the HTTP response.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll , I am not sure ... please check this url http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS#Routing_API..

Comment: @adham Doesn't look like it supports JSONP, so your second-best bet would be to create a server proxy (your script calls a file on your server, which then calls the remote server, and returns the result to your server, and then returns those results to your client script).

Comment: @adham, Look at my answer as it explains how to create a server proxy.

Comment: if i understand you , do you mean .. "js script calls a local php file which using restful functions then this retrieve the response from the remote server and get the result back to the js function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you control both parties then there a lot of options. Such as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), or [modifying header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) responses of the remote website. *Unfortunately*, JSONP only works if the remote website supports it. You **can't** force a JSONP call to a website that doesn't already support it.

However, as you have said, you only control the source website. You cannot hack the browser around this restriction for obvious reasons. You do have a third option which is creating a *back-end proxy*. You can use Apache and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to create a proxy. Here is on [how to do this](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/reverse-proxy-apache.html) or this [link](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/11/making-cross-sub-domain-ajax-xhr-requests-using-mod_proxy-and-iframes/) which is more detailed.

For example

```
ProxyPass /api/gtalkbots http://gtalkbots.com/reverse-proxy-data.php  
ProxyPassReverse /api/gtalkbots http://gtalkbots.com/reverse-proxy-data.php
```

Creates a proxy at `/api/gtalkbots` which will returns the repose from gtalkbots.com

Comment: It would be nice of you to provide some details or an example in your answer; if the links in your answer die then your answer is less useful in the future.

Comment: if i made js script >> local php file calls the remote server >> back the result to js script ... does that need to have a proxy ?

Answer (score 3):

Your best solution is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) calls.

```
 function jsonp(url, params, callback){
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", url+'?'+params+'&callback='+callback);
  script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  document.body.appendChild(script);
 }

 function doit(data){
  alert(data);
 }

jsonp('http://domain.com', 'foo=bar', 'doit');
```

In the opposite side, the website you're contacting must be able to return a JSONP formatted response in order for this to work.

Comment: JSONP only works if the remote website supports JSONP. You can't force a non-JSONP to suddenly support `callback=?`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do this, depending on whether the callee will ship out JSONP or not:

## 1. If you can, use JSONP

JSONP is a way to bypass the cross domain policy by returning a function call, rather than a naked JSON object. The P stands for padding, essentially just the part that calls the function.

For this to work, the callee needs to return JSONP.

Regular JSON looks like this:

```
{a: 12, b: 15}
```

JSONP looks like this:

```
callback({a: 12, b: 15});
```

When the AJAX request completes, the callback function (which you define in your own code) will be executed and the JSON data passed to it as an object, thus bypassing the cross domain policy.

## 2. If JSONP is not supported, mirror the request through your own server

The second option is to pipe data through your own server. Your JavaScript makes a request from your server, and the server then mirrors that request to the remote server and pings back the result.

Since the AJAX request is now made to your own server you won't run afoul of the cross domain policy.

There are two downsides to this approach:

1. Two requests are now required which will slow the response time a little, though probably not much as server to server communication will probably be via a fat pipe.
2. Since all requests now originate from your server you may have problems with IP based rate limits. This is the case with Twitter API calls. You may be able to mitigate against this by caching results.