# Parsing JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to load and dislay this JSON

http://eolis-sante.com/eolis/connexion.php?choice=1

I tried this , but it didn't worked

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://eolis-sante.com/eolis/connexion.php?choice=1",function(result){
          $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $(".tt").append(key.nom + "<br /> ");

        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Oh I just edited the code check it  again

Comment: Have you heard of [Same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) [Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Answer (score 1):

`$.each` is a bit different, it accepts function, that accepts index and an element:

```
$.each(result, function(index, element){
  $(".tt").append(element.nom + "<br /> ");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code from above is on the same domain as the http://eolis-sante.com/eolis/connexion.php?choice=1 ? You are not allowed to do an ajax call from a different domain. See this questions: 
[How to perform cross-site ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391249/how-to-perform-cross-site-ajax-request).

To avoid this security constrain you can make a server-side script on your server and read the content returned.

```
<?php
// connexion.php
echo file_get_contents('http://eolis-sante.com/eolis/connexion.php?choice=1')
?>
```

change your js to this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("connexion.php",function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $(".tt").append(field.nom + "<br /> ");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://eolis-sante.com/eolis/connexion.php?choice=1",function(result){
          $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $(".tt").append(value.nom + "<br /> ");
//                          ^ Key changed to value

        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you should have highlighted that you've changed `key` to `value`.